Python regularly failing to find files and directories on windows 11
I am currently attempting to build a wheel for a python library that I couldn't install directly on windows, though similar issues have been plaguing me since installing Python and getting PATH or various environment variables to work correctly has been a repeated issue.
Following the steps detailed here, issues pop up after setting my directory to jxlpy and running python -m pip wheel .
Originally it couldn't find the _jxl.cpp file in the _jxlpy subdirectory, though since the error now changed to not finding basetsd.h. I've repaired and reinstalled visual studio since with no luck and at first glance environment variables in windows settings look fine...
Here's the log for clarity
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.11.2
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools>cd C:\projects\jxlpy

C:\projects\jxlpy>python -m pip wheel .
Processing c:\projects\jxlpy
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cython (from jxlpy==0.9.5)
  File was already downloaded c:\projects\jxlpy\Cython-3.0.11-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: jxlpy
  Building wheel for jxlpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for jxlpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      copying jxlpy\JXLImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\jxlpy
      copying jxlpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\jxlpy
      running egg_info
      writing jxlpy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to jxlpy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to jxlpy.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to jxlpy.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'jxlpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'jxlpy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying jxlpy\JXLImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\jxlpy
      copying jxlpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-312\jxlpy
      running build_ext
      building '_jxlpy' extension
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" -I%INCLUDE% "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" /EHsc /Tp_jxlpy/_jxl.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-312\Release\_jxlpy/_jxl.obj -O2
      _jxl.cpp
      C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\pyconfig.h(230): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.41.34120\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for jxlpy
Failed to build jxlpy
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels


Reinstalling visual studio
Checking environment variables
Restarting the installation process from the beginning
Reinstalling python 3.12 (no other versions are installed)
Asked AI to fix it for me (GPT Grimoire and Claude 3.5 both keep assuming something is installed incorrectly or ask me to change the code in setup.py)

No effect for any of the solutions attempted, except that now it's failing before even getting to the part where it can't find the .cpp file.
